# Copy a file present in multiple folders under same name to different destination folder

Tags: file, for-loop, cmd, subdirectory

Here is my folder structure of folder A

```
A\Temp\folder1\c\one.txt
A\Temp\folder2\c\one.txt
A\Temp\folder3\c\one.txt
```

and another folder B

```
B\folder1.ext\c\   Note: the extension is part of its folder name.
B\folder2.ext\c\
B\folder3.ext\c\
```

What i want to do is to copy all the one.txt's from A\Temp*\c\one.txt to C*\c\

What i am trying now is:

```
for /D %%b in (TEMP\*) do (
set folder=%%~nb
ECHO %%~b
ECHO Copying %%b
ECHO.
ECHO.
COPY %%b\c\one.txt B\%folder%.ext\c
```

It doesn't work coz the foldername gettig stored in %folder% is only the name of the last folder (here folder3) everytime, ie the one.txt from the folder1 gets copied to C\folder3 and others dont get copied (system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign a loop variable to another variable inside the loop you have to enable delayed expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%b in (TEMP\*) do (
  set folder=%%~nb
  ECHO %%~b
  ECHO Copying %%b
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  COPY %%b\c\one.txt B\!folder!.ext\c
)
endlocal
```

Otherwise you have to use the loop variable:

```
for /D %%b in (TEMP\*) do (
  COPY %%~b\c\one.txt B\%%~nb.ext\c
)
```

The reason for this is that without delayed expansion, variables (`%folder%`) are expanded at *parse time*, i.e. when the command (block) is read. With delayed expansion enabled, variables (`!folder!`) are expanded at *run time*.